# Authenticate and Authorise in Both MVC and Http AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies

I get follow scenario which is working now:

MVC controller using `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` to authenticate user is authenticated or not, it will be using cookie.

API controller using `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` to authorise with bearer token.

I do also have angular http interceptor that verify and get bearer token for API purpose that can use among all angular `$http` request. But I am confusing how to achieve both after user has login?

This is current workflow

1. User click login, angular verify and store bears token in local storage.
2. After complete, manually trigger MVC controller so that it will get cookie for MVC authenticate.

This seem to me really double job, or I should focusing on using one `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Answer (score 0):

You need you use **Authorize** key to give permission to those functions where authorization is needed. And those functions can only be accessed when authorization token is generated and passed with http request.

```
module.service('tokenservice', function ($http) {
this.get = function () {
    var accesstoken = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    var logged_in = localStorage.getItem('logged_in').toString().trim() === 'false' ? false : true;
    var authHeaders = {};
    if (accesstoken && logged_in) {
        authHeaders.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + accesstoken;
    }

    return authHeaders;
};
});

module.controller('yourControllerName', function ( $http, tokenservice) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/Controller/MyFucntion',
        headers: tokenservice.get(),
    });
});
```

This will help you to get generated token in user login. After that You need to work with your controller

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult MyFucntion()
{
    //Your logic and calculation
    //return
}
```

Hope that will help

Comment: I have this already, my question is when navigate through page, or any request goes with MVC controller, I still use `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` attribute, which make me gonna take double work in login as MVC use cookie while Http use bearer token, so I need keep cookie and token all the way

Comment: Yes you have to keep them both

Comment: But this will cause the login process longer right, as I need get token first, then redirect to MVC controller in order to get cookie and home page.

Comment: That will cause a little bit more time, but its not a big deal according to my experience because our team is currently working on a project where we've used this. And its totally fine